# Making a REST api PUT call using cURL with query params

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm actually trying to make a REST api PUT call in a PHP application with the help of cURL.

Using 'Postman', when I run the following; it executes fine,

```
http://localhost:3000/testApi/updateTestComment?commentId=1&comment=test

{
  "Error": false,
  "Message": "Success",
  "Comments": {
    "fieldCount": 0,
    "affectedRows": 1,
    "insertId": 0,
    "serverStatus": 2,
    "warningCount": 0,
    "message": "(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0",
    "protocol41": true,
    "changedRows": 1
  }
}
```

But when I try to make the same call in a PHP application, I get an "Invalid json" error. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and was hoping to get some help. This is what I have so far,

```
$url = "http://localhost:3000/testApi/updateTestComment";
$curl = curl_init($url . "?commentId=comment_id&comment=comment_body");
$data = array(
  'comment_id' => $commentId,
  'comment_body' => $comment_body
  );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',"OAuth-Token: $token"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

// Make the REST call, returning the result
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (!$response) {
    die("Connection Failure.n");
}
```

Comment: should your request content type be application/json if you are posting data as multipart/form-data?

Comment: For PUT use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);`